# Child div of absolutely positioned parent not taking the full height of page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am having issues with a bug in a project I am working on.

The mobile menu which I want to take the full height of the viewport when it is less than 768px doesn't have a height even though I set it to 100%.

It will only be in view when toggled using the hamburger icon.

The `nav` element is **absolutely positioned** and the mobile menu is the last child element of the `nav` element.

The `nav` element is **absolutely positioned** so that the background is transparent and the `section` below it can be at the top of the page.

I want the `div` with class `mobile_links`to take up the full height of the page when toggled on mobile devices.

I have got a workaround to it which is to set the `position` property of the `section` below the `nav` to `relative` and set `top: -40px`.

I will have to set the `position` property of the `nav` element to `static` as well for this to work.

However, I don't like this because it leaves a space between the two `section` elements on the page.

Is there a way I can get the mobile menu to have 100% height without having to change the `position` properties that I have at the moment?

Here is the link to the page I am talking about: https://carifood-init.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot your `height: 100%` problem, have a look at this post:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

As an alternative, use `height: 100vh`.

*From the spec:*

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` units**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.
>
> - **vw unit** - Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.
> - **vh unit** - Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing
>     block.
> - **vmin unit** - Equal to the smaller of `vw` or `vh`.
> - **vmax unit** - Equal to the larger of `vw` or `vh`.

[Browser Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh) (viewport units have pretty much full support among major browsers, except IE 9, 10 and 11, and Edge, don't support `vmax`)

Answer (score 0):

use jquery for this job: There is an example i used to make height of a section 100% of screen (depending on the device that watch the page it will perform more or less height, so it's responsive).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var wheight = $(window).height();
    $('.section').css("min-height", wheight);
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps!